# How to enable Windows Search component in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, windows-server-2008

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 for development and also have installed Office Outlook in my system. Now I can't enable instant search withing Outlook. It's asking to enable to the search component. How to do this?

Update 06-01-2012 15:20 IST

As per @surfasb 's comment, I tried adding it from Server Manager->Roles->Add Roles but it isn't displaying Windows Search

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the right area - it's in the Role Services for the File Services...

[image]

It does say that Windows Search Services and Indexing service cannot be installed on the same computer.  This could be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Under the Server Manager, Go to Add Roles and look for Windows Search.

Comment: I updated the question! please check. Thank you

Comment: Surfasb, is an update needed?